# Solve the functional equation $\,\,f(2x)=2x f^\prime(x)$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, power-series, functional-equations, delay-differential-equations

If $f(x)$ is a real analytic functions on $\mathbb R$, and
$$2xf'(x)=f(2x),$$
then find $f(x)$.

My idea: express $f$ as:
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^n.$$

Thank you

Comment: You got that far, now apply the condition you require and equate coefficients of equal powers on both sides

Answer (score 6):

**Answer.** *The function $\,f$ is of the form $\,f(x)=ax+bx^2,\,\,$ for some constants $a$ and $b$.*

Explanation. Assume that $\,\,\displaystyle f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$, where $\lvert x\rvert<r$, for some $r\in(0,\infty]$. Then
$$
2xf'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2na_nx^n,
$$
while
$$
f(2x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n2^nx^n,
$$
and $2xf'(x)=f(2x)$ implies that
$$
2na_n=2^na_n, \quad\text{for all}\,\,n\in\mathbb N,
$$
and hence $a_0=0$, $a_1,a_2$ can be anything  since
$$
2\cdot a_1=2^1\cdot a_1 \quad\text{and}\quad 2\cdot 2\cdot a_2=2^2a_2,
$$
and
$$
a_n=0, \quad\text{for all}\,\,n>2.
$$

Indeed $f(x)=ax+bx^2$ satisfies the (delay differential) equation.

Comment: Why is $f$ analytic?

Comment: @Imanol by OP's assumption